# Listview with Cusror adapter displays nothing

Tags: java, android, simplecursoradapter

In my android app, I read some data from SQLite database and tried to display it into listview. Here is my code:

```
ListView listContent;
SQLiteAdapterno nadapter;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.ofrnumber);
listContent=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
nadapter=new SQLiteAdapterno(this);
nadapter.openToRead();
Cursor c=nadapter.queueAll();
String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapterno.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapterno.KEY_RCODE, SQLiteAdapterno.KEY_RNAME,SQLiteAdapterno.KEY_OFNO};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id,R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2,android.R.id.text2};
SimpleCursorAdapter  cursorAdapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row,c, from, to);
listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

SQLiteAdapterno:

```
public class SQLiteAdapterno {

public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME2 = "MY_DATABASEOFRN";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE2 = "MY_OFFERNO";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_RCODE = "rcode";
public static final String KEY_OFNO = "ofno";
public static final String KEY_RNAME = "rname";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE1 =
          "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE2 + " ("
          + KEY_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement, "
          + KEY_RCODE + " text, "
          + KEY_RNAME + " text, "
          + KEY_OFNO + " text);";

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private  SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Context context;
public SQLiteAdapterno(Context c)
{
    context=c;
}
public SQLiteAdapterno openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
      sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME2, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
      sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
      return this; 
     }
public SQLiteAdapterno openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
      sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME2, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
      sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      return this; 
     }
public void close(){
      sqLiteHelper.close();
     }
public long insert(String rcode, String rname, String ofno){
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put(KEY_RCODE, rcode);
      contentValues.put(KEY_RNAME, rname);
      contentValues.put(KEY_OFNO, ofno);
      return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE2, null, contentValues);
     }
public  Cursor queueAll(){
      String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_RCODE, KEY_RNAME, KEY_OFNO};
      Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE2, columns,
        null, null, null, null, null);
      return cursor;
     }
public int deleteAll(){
      return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE2, null, null);
     }
```

I didn't found the result, It doesn't show any items in Listview. Can someone say what is the mistake in this code and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure your cursor contains something? For instance log c.getCount()

Comment: can you print c.getCount(), from.size, to.size?

Comment: Yes, i didn't check it. cursor is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems good. Most likely your `Cursor` is empty. Try to add simple condition:

```
Cursor c = nadapter.queueAll();
if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
   // set Adapter
}
else {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Cursor is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If Toast will be shown, your `getAll()` method returns no data.

```
public  Cursor queueAll(){
   String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_RCODE, KEY_RNAME, KEY_OFNO};
   Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE2, columns,
        null, null, null, null, null);
   return cursor;
}
```

Here is problem.

Comment: Yes , sorry guys cursor is empty

Comment: @ling.s oks so now you fixed it, can you accept answer so? thanks

Comment: I've 1more doubt, what is int variables? I didn't understand.It didn't display results properly. It displays only hai hai. But i never used hai anywhere in my code

Comment: The problem is it only display rcode. all the remaining is displayed as "hai"

Comment: Oh.. sorry instead of row.xml can i use any others?

Comment: @ling.s no just i want to see how looks.